# How to mark text between elements with editable contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to make it so the user can select the text from the snippet like this with a single drag and drop. Is it possible with javascript? These are two identical divs with editable contents that have other elements in them. If they weren't editable you could select text across elements, but making them like this locks you in that element and also makes all text inside selectable regardless of css. Also I can't really use different css to make text unselectable because the divs need to have identical html. The only difference could be that the unselectable part of the div will not be visible, because the parent will have `overflow:hidden`.

[image]

It doesn't have javascript because I couldn't find anything online to help me even start. This website isn't a code writing service, so if it's possible to do the thing I'm asking about, could you at least give me a phrase to use while using the search engines?

```css
.edit-div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="edit-div">Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, shizzlin dizzle yippiyo elit. Nullam dizzle velizzle, for sure volutpizzle, suscipit shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle, gravida vizzle, izzle. Pellentesque egizzle tortor. <b>Sizzle eros. yo dolor dapibizzle boom shackalack shiz tempor.</b> <i>Maurizzle pellentesque nibh izzle yo. Gangsta izzle tortor. Pellentesque eleifend rhoncizzle own yo'.</i> In crazy get down get down owned dictumst. Fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle dapibizzle. Boofron tellizzle urna, pretium eu, mattizzle ac, eleifend vitae, hizzle. Dang suscipizzle. Boofron semper velit fizzle its fo rizzle.</div>
<div contenteditable="true" class="edit-div">Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, shizzlin dizzle yippiyo elit. Nullam dizzle velizzle, for sure volutpizzle, suscipit shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle, gravida vizzle, izzle. Pellentesque egizzle tortor. <b>Sizzle eros. yo dolor dapibizzle boom shackalack shiz tempor.</b> <i>Maurizzle pellentesque nibh izzle yo. Gangsta izzle tortor. Pellentesque eleifend rhoncizzle own yo'.</i> In crazy get down get down owned dictumst. Fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle dapibizzle. Boofron tellizzle urna, pretium eu, mattizzle ac, eleifend vitae, hizzle. Dang suscipizzle. Boofron semper velit fizzle its fo rizzle.</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what is the final goal for put `contenteditable`? Are the user could actually edit the content?

Comment: @MoshFeu The goal is a WYSIWYG text editor with multiple pages with each `.edit-div` working as a new page. The content should be the same so that the undo/redo functionality can be synced between them and the user should be able to treat all pages as a single document, including selecting the text.

Comment: Ok, so why the user needs to select across content across "pages"?

Comment: @MoshFeu The boss says so, why does it matter?

Comment: The thing is, I don't understand the full picture. Through my question I'm trying to understand.. So the  problem is that you want multiple `contenteditable` but the ability to select across them. I didn't understand the `overflow:hidden` part..

Answer (score -1):

**It is working for me**

select the text that has been marked after clicking the `Mark` button and for more doc: [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

```js
function markText() {
 
        // Get the selected text
        var selection = window.getSelection();

        // Check if there is a non-empty selection
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

            // Use execCommand to highlight the selected text
            document.execCommand('hiliteColor', false, 'yellow');

            // Clear the selection
            selection.removeAllRanges();
        }
    
}
```

```css
.edit-div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="edit-div">Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, shizzlin dizzle yippiyo elit. Nullam dizzle velizzle, for sure volutpizzle, suscipit shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle, gravida vizzle, izzle. Pellentesque egizzle tortor. <b>Sizzle eros. yo dolor dapibizzle boom shackalack shiz tempor.</b> <i>Maurizzle pellentesque nibh izzle yo. Gangsta izzle tortor. Pellentesque eleifend rhoncizzle own yo'.</i> In crazy get down get down owned dictumst. Fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle dapibizzle. Boofron tellizzle urna, pretium eu, mattizzle ac, eleifend vitae, hizzle. Dang suscipizzle. Boofron semper velit fizzle its fo rizzle.</div>
<div contenteditable="true" class="edit-div">Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, shizzlin dizzle yippiyo elit. Nullam dizzle velizzle, for sure volutpizzle, suscipit shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle, gravida vizzle, izzle. Pellentesque egizzle tortor. <b>Sizzle eros. yo dolor dapibizzle boom shackalack shiz tempor.</b> <i>Maurizzle pellentesque nibh izzle yo. Gangsta izzle tortor. Pellentesque eleifend rhoncizzle own yo'.</i> In crazy get down get down owned dictumst. Fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle dapibizzle. Boofron tellizzle urna, pretium eu, mattizzle ac, eleifend vitae, hizzle. Dang suscipizzle. Boofron semper velit fizzle its fo rizzle.</div>

<button onclick="markText()">Mark</button>
```

If you want to check if the browser supports `document.execCommand`

```
if (document.queryCommandSupported('hiliteColor')) {
   above code put here ...
}
else {
   console.error('The browser does not support document.execCommand');
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please stop posting random answers which don't address the question at all...